# Unable to import pandas in Linux environment

Tags: python, pandas, linux

In Linux Environment I have installed pandas using "pip install pandas"
but when I'm running python and using import pandas for that I'm getting such error

```
      >>> import pandas
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Is there anyways which automatically installs pandas library as a part of code in Linux environment

Comment: Your `pip` probably doesn't match your `python` version. Which mostly happens if you installed one or the other (or both) manually.

Comment: Try with `python -m pip install pandas` instead.

Comment: pandas has been installed but it's not getting executed

Comment: Did you install it the way I suggested?

Comment: yes I did try the same way also

Comment: try with ```pip3 install pandas```

Comment: How do you run Python?